# Traffic redirection question with Iptables

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, virtualbox, kubernetes

This is my first post!

[image]

After tracing PREROUTING:
kernel: TRACE: nat:PREROUTING:rule:1 IN=enp0s9 OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00......

OUT field is empty, what can i do? I would like to access the 200.10.50.202:8080 outside my network (over internet), I create this new adapter 192.168.15.62 inside my VM to help with this but no success, I appreciate any ideas, thank you so much for attention guys! kindly regards.

Answer (score 0):

Two things. Firstly, your NAT rule is incorrect. You have `200.100.50.202` instead of `200.10.50.202`. If this was typo and still does not work after rectifying, then move on to my next suggestion.

Secondly, your internet modem is pre-configured to block private IP addresses leaving the LAN to the public internet (WAN). It is also per-configured (chances are) to drop public IP addresses as the source IP from LAN to WAN.

Change your Kubernetes IP addresses from 200.X.X.X to private IP range such as 10.10.10.0/24, as per [RFC1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918). Then edit the NAT rule to point to new private IP address instead of `200.100.50.202`